# IOS view without Xib

Tags: ios, xib

I've to create iPAD app and xib files wont have to be used. When I place the components such as text boxes and labels through code they would be a bit off and its kind of really hard to place them exactly as in the design.

Is there any way that would help with this. Like I would get to know what are the exact positions without the help of a designer.

Comment: Don't know about such a tool, but +1 merely for building the UI from code.

Comment: Not sure if this is within the scope of stack overflow, but check out an application called Xscope.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a digital version of the intended design, like an image from the designer or even a scan from a paper design, you can use this a background image in a `UIView` and lay out your components on top of them in a temporary Xcode project with a `.xib` file.

Once laid out, you can make a note of the screen coordinates for each component and code these in your `.xib`-less project.

Comment: Or use graph paper, or just guess at frames and tweak iteratively.